# if mysql master is down, how does data attain consensus?

Tags: mysql

I am studying RAFT and find DB like ETCD is very resilient when the master is down. But how does DB like MYSQL handle this kind of failure?

For example, the order is paid in the master and is not yet sent to the slave, and at this time the master is down, one slave is elected as the new master. The order state in the slave (new master) is unpaid, and the user canceled this order. 1) Then the business is chaotic, and will this happen and need operators to get involved to handle business failer.

2)If the original master is on, how will the 2 nodes cooperate for the corrupted data?

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-solutions-switch.html  — as long as the log is seen, all is good. The “bad” scenario is if a tx commits and that change *cannot* be replicated before switching. This is the kind of scenario that DBAs can be called in the middle of the night. If the operation was still done in a tx, it will still be replicated atomically *if* it is replicated.

Comment: Probably more problematic to business rules overall to have something the like SQL Server master-master replication.. that’s a different can of worms than basic failover/HA though.